# How to sort array of objects by its boolean properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort this array of objects by its boolean properties however, I'm struggling to find a solution with javascripts 'sort' method

I'm trying to sort it, so the top item in the array would be 'offer = true', then 'shortlisted = true', and finally 'rejected = true'.

```
var toSort = [{
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: 2
}, {
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: false,
    rejected: true,
    stage: null
}, {
    offer: true,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: null
}, {
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: 1
}];
```

This is the final result I would like to achieve

```
[{
    offer: true,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: null
}, {
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: 1
}, {
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: true,
    rejected: false,
    stage: 2
}, {
    offer: false,
    shortlisted: false,
    rejected: true,
    stage: null
}]
```

What is the best method to sort this array?

Comment: How are you sorting this by the Boolean properties? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? How exactly do you want the array sorted?

Comment: Which field is this being sorted by?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post. I'm trying to sort the array based on the boolean properties that are true/false. In this case it should sort each item as follows - 'offer = true', then 'shortlisted = true', and finally 'rejected = true'.

Comment: Glad you accepted my answer but I believe @NenadVracar answer is the best one ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sort()` like this.

```js
var toSort = [{
  offer: false,
  shortlisted: true,
  rejected: false,
  stage: 2
}, {
  offer: false,
  shortlisted: false,
  rejected: true,
  stage: null
}, {
  offer: true,
  shortlisted: true,
  rejected: false,
  stage: null
}, {
  offer: false,
  shortlisted: true,
  rejected: false,
  stage: 1
}];

var result = toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.offer - a.offer ||
    b.shortlisted - a.shortlisted ||
    b.rejected - a.rejected
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign a numerical score to each object, setting a higher score for values of higher precedence. For example:

```
    var scoreObj = function(o) {
        var score = 0;
        if(o.offer) {
            score+=100;
        }
        if(o.shortlisted) {
            score+=10;
        }
        if(o.rejected) {
            score+=1;
        }
        return score;
    };
    var sorted = toSort.sort(function(a,b){
        return scoreObj(b) - scoreObj(a);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way :

```
toSort.sort(function(a, b){
    var numberA = a.offer * 5 + a.shortlisted * 3 + a.rejected;
    var numberB = b.offer * 5 + b.shortlisted * 3 + b.rejected;
    return numberA < numberB
});
```

Why this works :

1) we can treat boolean as 0 or 1, so if a.offer is true we are adding 5 to numberA, if not 0

2) If offer property is true, even if all other are true, offer will still appear first (because 5 > 1 + 3 = 4)

For more than 3 properties : This way we give a priority to the boolean properties you want first by giving it a numeric value that is greater than the sum of all the less priority properties

Comment: So why not 4 and 2 instead of 5 and 3..? That would make some binary sense to me..  [Nenad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41105161/4543207) seems better to me though.

Comment: @Redu indeed 4 and 2 would work as well, and I also believe the other answer is better ;)